# how to release chart indicator for cryptocurrency setup?

Tags: cryptography, pine-script, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi, indicator

I created an indicator of my own, but I can't make it accessible to other accounts.  could anyone tell me how? my indicator has its pine programming ready!  but I don't know how to let other people have access to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can publish scripts publicly or privately on TradingView using the "Publish script" button from the Editor. See the [usrman page on Publishing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Publishing.html) for more information.